# Getting information from another website using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I wonder if it is possible to get information from another web paguina via Javascript. If it would not be possible to do it using Javascript, I would like someone to explain to me what is the alternative to it.

What I want is to make a statistical operations of a web page in particular and I grab the information from that page to run statistics operations.

I found this:`parent.frames['page_name'].document.getElementById(id).value; parent.frames['page_name'].document.getElementByName(element_name).value;` This is possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: So [GET](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) the webpage?

Comment: Using ajaxP if it's not on the same domain

Comment: Assuming that this page is in different domain it is not possible to do it from javascript (cross site scripting). You need to implement gathering webpage from remote server to your server (i.e. using curl, it depends on your server side technology) and then serve it to the webpage.

Comment: I found this:
`parent.frames['page_name'].document.getElementById(id).value;
parent.frames['page_name'].document.getElementByName(element_name).value;`

This is possible?